# Why does file: prefix not working in @ContextConfiguration with my test using spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

My folder structure looks like :

```
project
    subproject
      src
       - main
          -java
       - test
          -java
          -resources
            -spring
              context.xml
```

when I try to use `@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/test/resources/spring/context.xml"})` my ide (intellij) shows `cannot resolve directory`. However, if I change the code to

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/spring/context.xml"})
```

or

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/spring/context.xml"})
```

The error disappears.

My original setting already has the following configure in pom.xml

```
<testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
</testResources>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading test resources like:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:spring/context.xml" })
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Actually in my case ```@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:spring/context.xml"})``` works,  but I still wonder why ```@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/test/resources/spring/context.xml"})``` doesn't work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: As far as I know, when you use `file` to load location, it checks absolute path from your root project. You may need to change location value to `file:subproject/src/test/resources/spring/context.xml` . Or may be it's just IntelliJ issue and build should work with maven command directly in cmd.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are right about the problem. When I added subproject in the path IntelliJ stop giving error.  Is is just IntelliJ being different? If I switch IDE (for example switching to eclipse), will the case be any different?

Comment: Try to run test from command prompt with command `mvn test` with and without subproject in file path. You will get idea whether it's code issue or IDE.